# Flutter parse emoji selected to textfield

Tags: flutter, textfield, emoji

I have an emoji-selector that works perfectly, but I would like to parse the emoji selected to `TextField` in Flutter. Below I have below my `TextField` and Emoji Selector.

```dart
Widget buildSticker() {
  return EmojiPicker(
    rows: 10,
    columns: 5,
    buttonMode: ButtonMode.MATERIAL,
    recommendKeywords: ["racing", "horse","Face","Ghost"],
    numRecommended: 10,
    onEmojiSelected: (emoji, category) {
   print(emoji);
    },
  );
}
```

I want the emoji picker to display on the `TextField` below:

```dart
TextField(
  controller: _controllerComment,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
),
```

My emoji return it print as : `Upside-Down Face, Emoji:`

Comment: Can you include package name/link?

Comment: ```emoji_picker```

Answer (score 0):

Add emoji into _controllerComment like this using [emoji_picker_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter),

```
onEmojiSelected: (category, emoji) {
    setState(() {
      _controllerComment.text = _controllerComment.text + emoji.emoji;
    });
  },
```

Comment: I'm not getting the emoji rather it shows:```Category.RECOMMENDED``` inside the ```TextField```

Comment: I am using emoji_picker_flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter) and it works fine.

Comment: I used ```emoji_picker:```